# Is it possible to build a dojo custom build without copying the dojo sdk into the project?

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I want to make a custom build of my Dojo project. For example, it is located at `D:/projects/myproject`,. and I have the Dojo SDK at `D:/programs/dojo1.8`. I want to separate Dojo and my project code to be independent of Dojo version.

When I'm building a custom package is it required to have the Dojo SDK in the same folder as the main project (i.e. `D:/projects/myproject/dojo`)? Or may I launch the Dojo builder in a totally unrelated folder, specifying my project's `package.js` as a parameter?

Such as `D:/programs/dojo1.8/buildscripts/build.bat --profile D:/projects/myproject/package.js`. If so, what should I use as the `basePath`, `releaseDir` and `packages` options in my `package.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include unrelated packages in the build.

In the command line specify the package you want to add, such as.

```
D:/programs/dojo1.8/buildscripts/build.bat --profile MyProfile.js --package d:\programs\dojo1.8
```

The specified package folder should contain a file named *package.json* with a package description. Format of the file could be found in dojo build documentation. Standard dojo, dijit and dojox packages have it. But nowhere said it must contain "directories: {lib: '.'}" entry to be built by dojo builder.

You may specify several packages separated by commas.